# KeyError: 'instance': send_activation_notification(kwargs['instance'])

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I am trying to implement registration in Django and faced with error:

> models.py", line 20, in user_registrated_dispatcher
>       send_activation_notification(kwargs['instance'])
>   KeyError: 'instance'

I submitted registration form then received this error message.[image]

**How can I solve the error?**

**Could you recommend good tutorial about registration with email in Django?**

Full code of the application located here (branch Login-version-2-site ): https://github.com/mascai/reg_app/tree/Login-version-2-site

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.dispatch import Signal
from .utilities import send_activation_notification


class AdvUser(AbstractUser):
    is_activated = models.BooleanField(default=True, db_index=True,
                                       verbose_name='Пpoшeл активацию?')
    send_messages = models.BooleanField(default=True, verbose_name='Слать оповещения о новых комментариях?')

class Meta(AbstractUser.Meta):
        pass


user_registrated = Signal(providing_args=['instance'])


def user_registrated_dispatcher(sender, **kwargs):
    send_activation_notification(kwargs['instance'])


user_registrated.connect(user_registrated_dispatcher)
```

**forms.py**

```
class RegisterUserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True, label="Email address")
    password1 = forms.CharField(label="Password", widget=PasswordInput,
                                help_text=password_validation.password_validators_help_text_html())
    password2 = forms.CharField(label="Password", widget=PasswordInput,
                                help_text=password_validation.password_validators_help_text_html())

    def clean_password1(self):
        password1 = self.cleaned_data['password1']
        if password1:
            password_validation.validate_password(password1)
        return password1

    def clean(self):
        super().clean()
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get('password1')
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get('password2')
        if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
            errors = {'password2': ValidationError('Введённые пароли не совпадают', code='password_mismatch')}
            raise ValidationError(errors)
        else:
            return self.cleaned_data


    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super().save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data['password1'])
        user.is_active = False
        user.is_activated = False
        if commit:
            user.save()
        user_registrated.send(RegisterUserForm, isinstance=user)
        return user

    class Meta:
        model = AdvUser
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'password', 'password2',
                  'first_name', 'last_name', 'send_messages')
```

**urls.py**

```
from .views import BBLoginView, BBLogoutView, profile, RegisterUserView, RegisterDoneView, user_activate

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.post_list, name='post_list'),
    path('accounts/login/', BBLoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
    path('accounts/profile/', profile, name='profile'),
    path('accounts/logout/', BBLogoutView.as_view(), name='logout'),

    path('accounts/register/done', RegisterDoneView.as_view(), name='register_done'),
    path('accounts/register/', RegisterUserView.as_view(), name='register'),
    path('accounts/register/activate/<str:sign>/', user_activate, name='register_activate'),
]
```

**views.py**

```
def post_list(request):
    return render(request, 'blog/post_list.html', {})


class BBLoginView(LoginView):
    template_name = 'blog/login.html'

class BBLogoutView(LoginRequiredMixin, LogoutView):
    template_name = 'blog/logout.html'

@login_required
def profile(request):
    return render(request, 'blog/profile.html')

class RegisterUserView(CreateView):
    model = AdvUser
    template_name = 'blog/register_user.html'
    form_class = RegisterUserForm
    success_url = '/register_done'

class RegisterDoneView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "blog/register_done.html"


def user_activate(request, sign):
    try:
        username = signer.unsign(sign)
    except:
        return render(request, 'blog/bad_signature.html')
    user = get_object_or_404(AdvUser, username=username)
    if user.is_activated:
        template = 'blog/user_is_activated.html'
    else:
        template = 'blog/activation_done.html'
        user.is_active = True
        user.is_activated = True
        user.save()
    return render(request, template)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You passed `isinstance=user` instead of `instance=user` when you send the signal inside the save method.

(Note, all this seems like a lot of work. There's already a general `post_save` signal you could use; but actually there doesn't seem to be much reason to use a signal at all. Why not just send the notification directly?

Comment: Thank you, sir! It works.
>> Why not just send the notification directly?
I followed tutorial. (I am new in django). Could you recommend tutorial about registration with email confirmation in Django?

Comment: Or recommend existing solution?